# What's the OOP way of dealing with a flow control heavy application?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, control-flow

I'm refactoring a huge WPF application whose complexity stems from the way it deals with flow control. It has a lot of "tiny business rules" that make it really difficult to make a modification without breaking something. These rules are things like

> If the window mode is foo but this is the first time they've pressed this button and the user has a certain role, show this, else validate another thing and show that, else show another thing.

I've thought about creating a lot of different classes for validation and keeping the global state but I'm not sure if there's a design pattern or something focused on dealing with this kind of situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style for control flow with validation checks](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148849/style-for-control-flow-with-validation-checks)

Comment: If you're not already doing so, a Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) approach eases this problem considerably.  See http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that might fit is a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  There are tools that help you build and visualize them but you can also model it with standard OOP practices.